# Use argument of function as parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

Sorry for the title that might be misleading but I cannot find a better and more concise way of describing my problem.

I need to obtain the type of a parameter of a function which is a parameter of another function, here's a little example of what I have now:

```
type StylingFn<T, P> = (
    theme: Theme,
    ...props: P extends undefined ? [undefined?] : [P]
) => StyleProp<T>;

const useTheme = <T, P = undefined>(
    styles: StylingFn<T, P>,
    ...styleProps: P extends undefined ? [undefined?] : [P]
) => {
    const theme: Theme = {}; // Example code
    return styles(theme, ...styleProps);
};
```

Basically I want to define a function `Fn` that *can* have a second parameter, this function in then passed to the `useTheme` function that uses it to type check its `styleProps` parameter.

The example above kind of works but it doesn't correctly infer the prop types, for example:

```
const Union = "a" | "b";

const s1 = (theme: Theme) => ({});
const s2 = (theme: Theme, {c}: {c: number}) => ({});
const s3 = (theme: Theme, {c}: {c: Union}) => ({});

useTheme(s1); // OK
useTheme(s2, {c: 12}); // OK
useTheme(s3, {c: "a"}); // Error
```

You can have a better look in this [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFhAttAvFA3gXwNwChSRQDKoANhAAoBOA9mADwwB8UaWe+40JIpAlgDsA5gDEBjADRQKLNAApgCZAC5YSiFIB02sLTABnVRSgQAHsAgCAJvqgBXaxABmgiFagB+KAG0HV565WHgC6UKreFMEAlKwsPOTUdIxMHADGNAL6wPb6EPBIqFCS0qz2ji4CbkxyWbwQhsRkgqLiMFIyWtq1CXoNxmYW1rZ+AZXuXr7lgSFhPpFRqvGUesmxGLhQm1DpmdmKBar5yKXsG1tUEMB2VAJQ3fUK6p2a94kGUXg4uJyEAIKlACIAIYAqAAHygAIAbgC0hksncyBAAPoARlKjwOagKMRQLDkWA+uB2CPuyIATBj9ipscgpOggZhVAzVL9MLj8egzpsAEbMzC4dkcOy5I4QGpItFEkV5dQSuoU+lA1TAgFCoA)

Comment: @TobiasS. sorry for that, should be working now

Comment: would [this](https://tsplay.dev/N91PjN) work for you?

Comment: @TobiasS. looks like it's working, easier than I expected, If you provide an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

The conditional infering of `P` seems to be the issue here. It is normally not necessary to create such conditionals since it is more convinient to let TypeScript infer missing or unspecified generic parameters to `never`.

```
type StylingFn<T, P> = (theme: Theme, ...props: P[]) => StyleProp<T>;

const useTheme = <T, P = undefined>(styles: StylingFn<T, P>, ...styleProps: P[]): StyleProp<T> => {
    const theme: Theme = {};
    return styles(theme, ...styleProps);
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=3&pln=4&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFhAttAvFA3gXwNwChSRQDKoANhAAoBOA9mADwwB8UaWe%2040JIpAlgDsA5gDEBjADRQKLNAApgCZAC5YSiFIB02sLTABnVRQDaAXQCUrFj3LU6jJhwDGNAfuBQArvojwkqKElpVi8BABMIADNBCDCmOXdeCENiMkFRcRgpGS1tRNs9FJMLVRtKPQcrDFwoWqgXNw9Ff1U-ZBD2GrqqCGBPKgEofOSFdVzNYbsDczwcXE5CAFUBPlcQgCIAQ3WoAB8odYAjdedXdyGARhDRlrV-SxQWOSwZ3Abz-QAma%20aVO%20QpOgnJhVEDVAJPIhDhAqJgHk8Xnh3h59ABmH7qVpjDDA0FOVTLVYCOFVZ5wjjeXzqBIXGZQAD09KgAHkANK4SltCAJT6A-FQC6fckMplsjk%20LkJVF81RbdbCxks1lAA)